# Where are the resources on the prime number theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, education

I am looking for resources which explain the prime number theorem to 18 year old students. I am not seeking a proof of the result but something which will have an impact and motivate a student to study mathematics in the future. Can anyone provide or direct me to these resources?

Comment: As a rule I think *unsolved* problems are more motivating than solved problems. Especially *tractable* unsolved problems, and underdeveloped mathematics that could bring monetary gain.

Comment: There is nothing contained in the prime number theorem that is advanced...it is the proof that is tough not the theorem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good book is "What is Mathematics" by R. Courand and H. Robbins. The chapter "The Theory of Numbers", in particular the section "Prime numbers" there, might be exactly what you are looking for.